# "npm start" throws Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm new to reactJS.I was following the steps given in one tutorial. When I type "npm start" I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR in ./main.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In C:\Users\user\Desktop\reactApp\node_modules\babel-preset-es2015\lib\index.js
    at createDescriptor (C:\Users\user\Desktop\reactApp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:178:11)
    at items.map (C:\Users\user\Desktop\reactApp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:109:50)
    at Array.map (native)
    at createDescriptors (C:\Users\user\Desktop\reactApp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:109:29)
    at createPresetDescriptors (C:\Users\user\Desktop\reactApp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:101:10)
    at passPerPreset (C:\Users\user\Desktop\reactApp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:58:96)
    at cachedFunction (C:\Users\user\Desktop\reactApp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\caching.js:33:19)
    at presets.presets (C:\Users\user\Desktop\reactApp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:29:84)
    at mergeChainOpts (C:\Users\user\Desktop\reactApp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:315:26)
    at C:\Users\user\Desktop\reactApp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:278:7
    at buildRootChain (C:\Users\user\Desktop\reactApp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:68:29)
    at loadPrivatePartialConfig (C:\Users\user\Desktop\reactApp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\partial.js:57:55)
    at Object.loadPartialConfig (C:\Users\user\Desktop\reactApp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\partial.js:82:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\reactApp\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:82:26)
    at next (native)
    at step (C:\Users\user\Desktop\reactApp\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:3:221)
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./main.js main[1]
```

Can someone please help me find the solution?

package.json

```
{
  "name": "npm",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": { "start": "webpack-dev-server" },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "webpack": "^4.17.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
var config = {
  entry: "./main.js",
  output: { path: "/", filename: "index.js" },
  devServer: { inline: true, port: 8080 },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        query: { presets: ["es2015", "react"] }
      }
    ]
  }
};
module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Please show your package.json

Comment: {
  "name": "npm",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "webpack": "^4.17.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0"
  }
}

Comment: Please update your question with webpack.config.js file

Comment: var config = {
   entry: './main.js',
   output: {
      path:'/',
      filename: 'index.js',
   },
   devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 8080
   },
   module: {
      rules: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
module.exports = config;

Comment: Below is the config file

Comment: I couldn't update so I have posted in comment. please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var config = {
  entry: "./main.js",
  output: { path: "/", filename: "index.js" },
  devServer: { inline: true, port: 8080 },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        query: { presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"] }
      }
    ]
  }
};
module.exports = config;
```

since its babel 7, it has to be namespaced, `@babel`...

Comment: Now I'm getting  "Compiled with warnings."

Comment: what are those warnings?

Comment: Not sure..getting "WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled with warnings."

Comment: just do what the error is saying, add mode:"production" or "development" to your webpack config, it is straight forward...

Comment: Hi I installed "npm install react-router-dom" and now again I'm getting the error.

Comment: ERROR in ./main.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions.

Comment: can you please help me